# How to add a custom button to navbar?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am creating a Rubymotion app and I need to create a custom button in the Navbar.
I am running the code in the controller.

*I am using this code:*

```
button = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.init
    button.title = 'Add'
    button.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
    button.target = self
    button.action = 'performAdd'
    button.setBackgroundImage(checkInImage, forState:UIControlStateNormal, forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
    button.setBackgroundImage(checkInPressed, forState:UIControlStateHighlighted, forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

*But I get this error when running rake:*

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'first_controller.rb:21:in `button': undefined method `setBackgroundImage' for #<UIBarButtonItem:0x6b3c1d0> (NoMethodError)
```

**SOLUTION**

```
    button = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.init
        button.title = 'Add'
        button.target = self
        button.action = 'performAdd'
        button.setBackgroundImage(checkInImage, forState:UIControlStateNormal, barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
        button.setBackgroundImage(checkInPressed, forState:UIControlStateHighlighted, barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my reading, it's `barMetrics`, not `forBarMetrics`. So:

```
setBackgroundImage(checkInImage,
                   forState:UIControlStateNormal, barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
```

Comment: By the way, RubyMotion just released API documentation so you can see the proper methods in Ruby instead of having to use Apple's Obj-C reference: http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/UIBarButtonItem.html#setBackgroundImage%3AforState%3AbarMetrics%3A-instance_method

Answer (score 1):

I am Really new in `RubyMotion but still trying to help you.please forgive me if i am not correct on any place.

**EDIT:**
Seeing your Crash Log `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'first_controller.rb:21:in`button': undefined method `setBackgroundImage' for #<UIBarButtonItem:0x6b3c1d0> (NoMethodError)`.
I think ,You are not calling the right  method for setting the backgroundImage in your `View controller` that's Why Such Exception coming,I guess so.

And I think Exact Reason Could be the `setBackgroundImage` Method.I guess that is not correct method .it should be  `backgroundImage`.Then You should try below line of Code in your `ViewController`.

```
  button.backgroundImage(checkInPressed, forState:UIControlStateHighlighted, forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault).
```

Here is your Code just changing that single line.

```
  button = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.init
  button.title = 'Add'
  button.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
  button.target = self
  button.action = 'performAdd'
  button.backgroundImage(checkInImage, forState:UIControlStateNormal, forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
  button.backgroundImage(checkInPressed, forState:UIControlStateHighlighted, forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

[Here is The Link For The same You should take a View of this Link.](http://rubymotion-tutorial.com/4-containers/)

I hope  you could get some Idea..

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle Sorry I realised same thing i went on wrong way.sorry again... i am going to delete or edit it.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle Thanks and now I am searching for the Solution so that i could edit my answer...

Comment: Thank you! But this did not help either.

Comment: @JonathanClark  dude No need to say thanks i am very glad to help anyone over StackOverflow.Well your exception log display the same reason behind that Crashed.ok Nops, Have you tried that Link Mention in My answer?